# Clipping raster error 4

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, clip, error

I'm on QGIS 3 and have used the 'AusMap' plugin to upload google maps raster images and a 5m LiDAR DEM. I have created a shapefile (polygon) and now I want to clip the raster files to the extent of the polygon. Whether I 'clip by extent' or 'clip by mask layer', I still run into the same issue--an error 4.

Here is the error message:

> "2021-02-24T22:56:39     INFO    gdal_translate -projwin 151.917322934
> -32.444796101 151.936019747 -32.45118951 -of GTiff "identifier=1&url=http://services.ga.gov.au/gis/services/DEM_LiDAR_5m/MapServer/WCSServer?"
> "C:/Users/curti/OneDrive/Documents/GIS Base/the_block/clip.tif"
> 2021-02-24T22:56:39     INFO    GDAL execution console output
> ERROR 4: `identifier=1&url=http://services.ga.gov.au/gis/services/DEM_LiDAR_5m/MapServer/WCSServer?'
> does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a
> supported dataset name."

There seems to be some issue with the LiDAR file, but I don't understand what the problem is or how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: You're trying to clip a WMS service, that wont work.

Comment: Ahh yes you're right. I've been able to find tips on how to address that by searching "clipping from a WMS service". Thanks